# opening html files with Firefox get error

Tags: html, windows, firefox

I get the error "There was a problem sending a command to the Program" when opening html files with firefox, the file does look ok though when firefox loads it up. So this isn't a life shattering problem but maybe it indicates a serious issue somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Try updating your firefox to latest version i.e 28.0.
2. Open Task Manager and end firefox processes and then try opening those files again.